# group by of one column and having count of another

Tags: sql

I have a table 'customer' which contains 4 columns

```
name day         product price
A    2021-04-01  p1      100
B    2021-04-01  p1      100
C    2021-04-01  p2      120
A    2021-04-01  p2      120
A    2021-04-02  p1      100
B    2021-04-02  p3      80
C    2021-04-03  p2      120
D    2021-04-03  p2      120
C    2021-04-04  p1      100
```

With a command

```
SELECT COUNT(name) 
  FROM (SELECT name 
          FROM customer 
         WHERE day > '2021-03-28' 
           AND day < '2021-04-09' 
         GROUP BY name 
        HAVING COUNT(name) > 2)
```

I could count number of customer that bought something more than twice in a period of time.

I would like to know in each day (GROUP BY over day) how many customers bought something with this condition that in a period they bought something more than twice.

**Suggested Edit:**

For above example A and C are valid agents by the condition.
The desired output will be:

```
day            how_many
2021-04-01     2
2021-04-02     1
2021-04-03     1
2021-04-04     1
```

Comment: (1) You should include the desired results in the question.  (2) Tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question as wanting to know how many customers made more than one purchase on each day.  If so, one method uses two levels of aggregation:

```
select day,
       sum(case when day_count >= 2 then 1 else 0 end) 
from (select c.name, c.day, count(*) as day_count
      from customer c
      group by c.name, c.day
     ) nc
group by day
order by day;
```